# Uncle timestamp validity

Tags: mining, timestamp, uncle-blocks, ghost-protocol

Regarding acceptance/rejection of uncle blocks, what are acceptable block timestamps for an uncle block?

Say:
block123_timestamp = Y
uncle123_timestamp = X

Where X < Y. Is uncle123 a valid uncle, even though it was stated to be produced earlier by its miner?

Thank you!

Comment: From the top of my head the only requirement in the Yellow paper is that an uncle block has to be a valid block, ie uncle_timestamp >= uncle_parent_timestamp. But there's no additional conditions regarding niece blocks.

Comment: @Ismael Yep, I just re-read the yellow paper, a valid ommer simply needs to be a valid header of the block it is referencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### According to the Ethereum yellow paper:

Ommer Validation. The validation of ommer headers means nothing more than verifying that each ommer header is both a valid header and satisfies the relation of Nth-generation ommer to the present block where N ≤ 6. The maximum of ommer headers is two.

This is found on section 11.1 on http://yellowpaper.io